How to play tremolo acting like a fall
I’m practicing “Easy Street” from Annie. I have tremolos acting like a fall, and the other way around too. How do I play these? I know a tremolo is like a trill, but what happens when I’m using them like a fall?
It’s at the end of bar 50 and in bar 55


Most likely they’re unconventional notations for falls and slide ins.

@Lazy Yeah pretty sure that’s just meant to be a fall and it’s badly engraved. You’d think MT would be a place for top engravers but it’s definitely not. Regarding the question itself, I’d assume these are falls and ask the MD what they want. Or play it as falls and see if MD corrects you or not. Also listening original cast recording might help.

Please [edit] your question, ensure that it title better summarizes the post and avoid any "please help" text in any part of your post (including the title), because it's not relevant to search results and, besides, it's obviously clear that you need help, otherwise you wouldn't ask a question.

Sorry to be picky, but a tremolo is not the same as a trill.

In a tremolo you alternate rapidly between two different fingerings for the same pitch.

In a trill you alternate rapidly between two adjacent different pitches.


The sample page you provided has two different notations for note connections - in bars 43, 65 and 66 there's a wavy line and in bars 50 and 55 you have a bold straight line. These should be performed differently.
I'd suggest the straight line as a portamento, i.e. continuous pitch bend, whilst the wavy line looks like some sort of trill/waggle+bend while connecting the two notes. Might even be flutter tongued.
Impress your music director by giving them the option - be able to perform the notation using portamento or flutter tongue or waggle+bend and let them choose.

Thank you, I spoke with the director today and that’s what he said it would be a pitch bend. Thanks for your help!

There is very much such a thing as tremolo between two notes, and a trill can be interpreted as a special case of this (though as an ornament in a different function). Also the "wavy line" is standard notation for glissando.
